# How can I access Bluemix Conversation variables from Swift

Tags: swift, ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

I have defined a Conversation dialog, in which I set the variable repeat in one node:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "You said: <?input_text?>. Let's fix the @product. "
  },
  "context": {
    "repeat": "<?input.text?>"
  }
}
```

and have displayed the variable $repeat in a subsequent node:

```
{
  "output": {
    "text": "repeat: $repeat"
  }
}
```

How can I access this variable $repeat in Swift?
I can access response.input.text, which contains the same text, but I'd like to access $repeat, in order to be more flexible.

Input:

```
radio broken
```

Output:

```
You said: radio broken. Let's fix the radio.
repeat: radio broken
```

Swift code:

    `var context: Context? // initial definition
    ...`

```
func next_dialog(input_text: String) {
    conversation = Conversation(username: username, password: password, version: version)
    let failure = { (error: NSError) in print(error) }
    conversation.message(workspaceID, text: input_text, context: self.context, failure: failure) { response in 
         self.context = response.context  // update with response.context
```

...

Context:

[image]

Comment: Your "repeat" variable will be in the context object that returns from your conversation call. But this to me looks more like how to access JSON in swift?

Comment: Added the context, can not see repeat.

Comment: Added the input, output & code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, the [Watson Developer Cloud iOS SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk) does not currently support accessing user-defined context variables from the Conversation service. It's a feature that we are working on, though, and hope to release soon.

The best place to track progress is by following [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/ios-sdk/issues/426).

It's not a solution, but I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, based on what you have shown I believe what you are doing is setting a context variable from within Conversation.

However the state needs to be maintained at the application layer. So you need to send in the context variable with your conversation input, or it will not be sent back.

If this isn't the case, then you need update your question with sample input + output again.